# Is there anyway to create a 9-patch without distorting the text inside the image?

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

I'm actually trying to create many images (chat bubbles) with text inside them and obviously on using 9-patch it gets distorted. Is there an alternative way to save the text from distortion and simultaneously enlarging it along with the image(chat bubble)?

Comment: Can't you just enlarge the image, and then put text over the image? You typically don't want your text to be an image. You want it coded in.

Comment: I need many of them and most of them just vary in size (with the content being same),so coding would just complicate things.

Comment: Not as complicated  as what you're trying to do with a nine patch. But you create an image out of your text and draw it over the nine patch.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of 9-patches is to separate text from background. You setup the form of your background bubble and mark the stretchable area and padding. In LibGDX all you have to do is create a `Labelstyle` that takes that 9-patch bubble as a background and put text in it. The bubble will stretch as your text increases. This however works best for squarish backgrounds but can work for your bubbles with a little tweaking and if you don't stretch them too crazy.